# Java spec unchecked exception "must" be caught

Tags: java, exception, specifications

I am reading about exceptions here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

and it says that the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` "must be caught" in the code comments.

I thought unchecked exceptions don't have to be caught.

Is this just a typo?

Comment: Yeah, very likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException extends from java.lang.RuntimeException
which is unchecked exceptions.

So to answer your question. This should be a typo.